# Add a new "Interaction Mode" (Like Edit and Object Mode)

Tags: python, interface, add-on

Is there any way at all of adding my own Interaction Mode to Blender?

[image]

By this I mean it appears in the dropdown with Edit Mode and Object mode; can have its own hotkeys separate from other interaction modes; and its own buttons on the side panels.

I don't mind more complex things. I also don't mind C++ if I really have to. Just so long as a casual user is able to install the add-on in a normal way, a fork isn’t viable.